# Binary search in c

Tags: c, search

I wrote a code with function and using strcmp.I entered 5 names in the program (one of them is **sara**).and when i search for them i can find all of them but not sara. why when i search sara it can't be find?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fbubble(char [][21],int);
int fsearch(char [][21],char [],int);
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    const int n=5;
    int i;
    char name[21],a[n][21];
    printf("enter 5 name\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        gets(a[i]);
    fbubble(a,n);
    printf("enter name to search\n");
    gets(name);
    if(fsearch(a,name,n)==-1)
        printf("name not exist in the table\n");
    else printf("name exist in the table\n");
        getch();
    return 0;
}
//**********************************************
void fbubble(char a[5][21],int n){
    int i,j;
    char temp[21];
    for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)
        for(j=0;j<i;j++)
            if(strcmp(a[j],a[j+1])>0){
                strcpy(temp,a[j]);
                strcpy(a[j],a[j+1]);
                strcpy(a[j+1],temp);
            }
}
//**********************************************
int fsearch(char a[5][21],char name[21],int n){
    int mid,low=0,high=n-1;
    while(low<high){
        mid=(low+high)/2;
        if(strcmp(name,a[mid])<0)
            high=mid-1;
        else if(strcmp(name,a[mid])>0)
            low=mid+1;
        else return mid;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in your debugger to see what's going on ?

Comment: What are the names other than 'sara' that you entered? What was the order you entered the names? Have you printed out the array of names before and after the sort? Is the name present after the sort? Is the data sorted after the sort? You should also immediately forget that the function `gets()` ever existed and never use it again. It is no longer part of standard C and is too dangerous to use in even throwaway code.

Comment: I tried debugger but there were not any error.

Comment: Have you seen the `qsort` and `bsearch` functions in `stdlib`?

Comment: i used Bubble sort and binary search.
names.reza,ahmad,masoud,ali,sara

Comment: `strcmp` is case sensitive.

Comment: i used lower case for both print and search

Comment: Given input names 'fred',
'sara',
'alan',
'zoe',
'adam' in that order, it finds 'sara' (or says it does — there's no echoing of inputs or other validation). However, with your list of names, it does not find 'sara'. So, learn how to print useful data out of a program so you can work out what's wrong.

Comment: did you try the name that i gave?with your name program works,but with mine no.

Comment: The sort code seems to work.  The problem is the search code. I think C.B has the correct answer.  As written, you can't find the last name in the table; as fixed, it can.  But the first thing to learn is how to debug, and the first, most rudimentary debugging technique is 'print the data' — as it is read, and as it is processed.  You should also identify where the entry is found (print the return value from `fsearch()`).

Comment: Also remember the risk for integer overflow [as described here](http://googleresearch.blogspot.se/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's about your comparison of high and low

Let's think about this logically

We have

```
['ahmad','ali','masoud','reza','sara']
  0        1       2       3      4
```

`high = 4`, `low = 0`, `mid = 2`

`masoud != sara`

`low = mid+1 = 3`

`mid = 7/2 = 3`

`reza != sara`

`low = mid+1 = 4`

`high>low == false;break;`

To Fix:

you want `while(low<=high)`